# JOOQ dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, jooq

Say for example my function accepts a parameter called 'entityType', and according to that it queries the table `entityType_other_stuff`.

Is this possible to implement in JOOQ on runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to create dynamic `org.jooq.Table` objects by name is to use [`DSL.table(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Name-) as in:

```java
String parameter = "entityType";
Table<?> table = table(name(parameter + "_other_stuff"));
```

If you use the standard [`Settings.renderNameStyle`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderNameStyle) [`QUOTED`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/RenderNameStyle.html#QUOTED), then the identifier will be quoted and escaped, and thus SQL-injection safe.

For more information, see the manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names